# how transmit to function "event" and other parameters, for example "this"

Tags: javascript

I want get x and y coordinates from click on span elements.

```
<span id="username" onclick="username(this);">[Василий]:</span>
```

How right give "this" to the function var t, because now it going to "event", and next error `TypeError: t is undefined`

```
function username(event, t) {
        event = event || window.event;
        alert(event.clientX); // undefined
        var nick = t.innerHTML.slice(1, t.innerHTML.length-2);
}
```

Comment: Bind your event using Javascript, then this will be much easier.

Comment: You don't need to pass `this`; just use `event.currentTarget`. Even better would be to do as @lonesomeday mentions and bind using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass all the arguments you want, in the order you want them.

```
onclick="username(event, this)";
```

You are better off avoiding using intrinsic event attributes in the first place though.

```js
document.getElementById("username").addEventListener("click", username);

function username(event) {
  alert(event.clientX);
  var nick = this.innerHTML.slice(1, this.innerHTML.length - 2);
  alert(nick);
}
```

```html
<span id="username">[Василий]:</span>
```

You'd also be better off using an HTML element designed to be clicked on (and which appears in the tab order by default, and which plays nicely with screen readers). i.e. use a `<button>`, not a `<span>`.